# What is the most similar AIX-like linux/unix OS available?

Tags: linux, unix, aix

The question tells everything :)

**What is the most similar AIX-like linux/unix that is free and also capable to be installed on a VM so that i can do some practice?**

I need to do some testing before starting to actually work, and there is an AIX server out there that I have to config. I have some intermediate linux experience (ubuntu, openSUSE, HP-UX), however I have never configured an AIX before.

To my knowledge one must have an IBM server in order to run AIX (I don't have such), so what is the closest linux or unix or whatever.. similar to AIX, that I can practise on and I also have to install it on a VM because I don't have any other free hardware :)?

Like for example CentOS is most similar to RedHAT? Well I think that by now you all get my point :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Rosetta Stone for UNIX guide](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html). Select "AIX" and "Linux" in the upper-left corner, then click "Draw Table". This will show you some command equivalents to help get you started.

Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/how-to-run-a-fresh-version-of-aix-in-a-virtual-machine-with-a-linux-host

Answer (score 2):

CentOS is like RHEL because they come from the same source code. AIX is a [UNIX 03 Compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification) operating system so any other [compatible OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Registered_UNIX_systems) will work to some extent. In reality what makes AIX, AIX is the proprietary stuff so while you can learn the UNIX, learning AIX isn't really practical on a non AIX system.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about that! And do not lose your time to try to run AIX on linux. Even then, you would not use any feature of Power processor, which makes AIX really powerful OS.

Differentiating UNIX and Linux
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix_rhel/?S_TACT=105AGY20&S_CMP=HP

Some good links

http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_unixes/AIX/index.shtml

http://www.ahinc.com/aix/index.htm

http://unixwerk.net/en/aix/index.html

http://www.tablespace.net/quicksheet/aix-quickstart.html

http://www.ahinc.com/aix/index.htm

IBM has good documentation for AIX, but they are very long. I don't like AIX manpages, they are not clear enough and sometimes they don't explain well some outputs etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but (i'll have to go offtopic) why are you hiding the links with `hxxp` ?

Comment: @Spirit: New users can't post lots of links is the reason for hxxp